# how to show nested json data/ extjs4?

Tags: c#, json, nested, extjs4, tuples

i have a function that return 7 values, i used a tuple to return them since they dont have the same type
then i serelizes it
so i can read my resulted json in my js script , and i can access it via ItemN

take a look at the code:

```
 public JArray getJsonData( )
    {             

        //my queries here//  

        var vl = new List<Tuple<string, string,  string, int, int, double, string >>();

        vl.Add(new Tuple<string, string,  string,int, int, double, string>
             (item.Date , item.Adress,  name, item.login, pwd, role, id));                
        }

        JArray o = JArray.FromObject(vl);

        return o;          
    }
```

my extjs4 store:

```
var myStore2 = new Ext.data.JsonStore({

fields: ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Item4', 'Item5', 'Item6', 'Item7'] ,

data: []
});
```

the problem is that now i need to return another element which make them 8 elements in my tuple
so i get this funny error

```
the eight element of an eight tuple must be a tuple
```

so i add my eight element as a tuple as requested.

the problem is that now i get this json format: (notice 'Rest' at the end)

```
{Item1:"27-09-2011",Item2:"LA",Item3:"armance",Item4:"astrocybernaute",Item5:"P@ssw0rd",Item6:"Admin",Item7,Rest : {Item1 : 26 }}
```

**the problem is that i dont know how to access it in my extjs4 store. Item8 of course doesnt work,Rest doesnt work,item1 doesnt either!!**

any idea plz?

thank you for ur time

**EDIT** this is my new store after Matt Greer suggestion

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
extends: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
        { name: 'Item1' },
        { name: 'Item2' },
        { name: 'Item3' },
        { name: 'Item4' },
        { name: 'Item5' },
        { name: 'Item6' },
        { name: 'Item7' },
        { name: 'Item8', mapping: 'Rest.Item1' }
]
 });

 var myStore2 = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
 model: 'MyModel',
 proxy: {
     type: 'ajax',
     url: '',
     autoLoad :true,
     reader: {
         type: 'json'
             } 
        }
 });
```

but it still not working

**SOLUTION**
I want to point out that Store.loadData does not respect the field mapping

The issue is that the sencha team changed loadData's behavior, AND it's not something that's documented in a way that is clear.

Add the following to your code base (above your app code, but below ext-all.js):

```
Ext.override(Ext.data.Store, {
loadDataViaReader : function(data, append) {
    var me      = this,
        result  = me.proxy.reader.read(data),
        records = result.records;

    me.loadRecords(records, { addRecords: append });
    me.fireEvent('load', me, result.records, true);
}            
});
```

then use:

```
mystore2.loadDataViaReader(data)
```

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but maybe you should check out Dextop as it solves many .NET/Ext JS data connection issues. https://github.com/codaxy/dextop

Comment: msdn says: "The .NET Framework directly supports tuples with one to seven elements. In addition, you can create tuples of eight or more elements by nesting tuple objects in the Rest property of a Tuple(Of T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, TRest) object." source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx

Comment: yeah i got this, the problem is after i do this i dont know how to read nested json data into my extjs grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where that Tuple error is coming from. octuples are supported by .NET as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd386921.aspx)

Give this a try

```
var myTuple = Tuple.Create(3,4,5,8,12,4,12,99);
```

myTuple should be a octuple of 8 ints.

But, if you still get that error and you must work around it in Ext, you can use mappings. You need to define a Model, and in the Model's fields use a mapping to grab that last value:

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
    extends: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
            { name: 'field1' },
            // fields 2 through 7
            { name: 'field8', mapping: 'Rest.Item1' }
    ]
 });

 var myStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    model: 'MyModel',
    // ...
  });
```

I've never actually tried defining fields right on the store, I assume Ext is creating a Model automatically for you. So you could probably do the mapping right in the store as well.

Comment: thanks for ur reply, to warn u im still new to both .net and extjs. yes octuples are supported but the eight item should be a tuple (TRest),look at ur link,its there.But img going to test it again to make sure.

Comment: i'll also try ur second suggestion   but i never understood how models work exactly..

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct. That's an interesting limitation. In that case, it sounds like you need to use Ext to get around this. My example above should work. First I'd try just adding the `mapping` property to your eighth field in your store. If that's a no go, just define a model like above and tell your store to use it.

Comment: this is how i called my store, is it right ? it seems there is a problem ,it doesnt load ,timout expired :(  `var mystore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
     model: 'MyModel',
     proxy: {
         type: 'ajax',
         url : '',
         reader: {
             type: 'json'
                 } 
            }
 });`

Comment: Can you include your complete code somewhere? What you posted here looks correct, so there is probably something else tripping up. Also make sure you either set `autoLoad` to true or call `load()`

Comment: updated my question,is this what u wanted to see? after i added autoLoad,i still have timeout expired!

Comment: `autoLoad` is a property on the store, not the proxy. If you take that exact code as you have it and just add a call to `myStore2.load()` afterwards, it should load, or at least give you another error that you can ponder on.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3905/discussion-between-astrocybernaute-and-matt-greer)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution run when we used the loadData method, **and when the proxy used is a `Memory` proxy.**

In fact, It seems that **EXTJS can not map datas when its a memory proxy**. but when **its a Ajaxs proxy it can map the datas and fields**.

Exemples with memory proxy

```
var fields = [
            {name: 'id', mapping: 'id'},
            {name: 'code', mapping: 'code'},
            {name: 'code', mapping: 'exercice'},
            {name: 'code', mapping: 'code'},
            {name: 'typeDocument', mapping: 'typeDocument'},
            {name: 'utilisateur', mapping: 'editionJobs[0].utilisateur'},
            {name: 'dateCreation', mapping: 'editionJobs[0].dateCreation'},
            {name: 'jobId', mapping: 'editionJobs[0].id'},
            {name: 'avenant', mapping: 'editionJobs[0].avenant'},
            {name: 'etat', mapping: 'editionJobs[0].etat'}
        ];

        var data = [];


        store = new Ext.data.Store({
            fields: fields,
            proxy: {
                type: 'memory',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'listDossier'
                }
            },
            listeners: {
                load: function(store, records, options) {
                    store.fireEvent('datachanged', store);
                }
            }
        });

Ext.getCmp('listeEditionDossierGridPanel').getStore().loadDataViaReader(listDossier); // OK, thx for the method ;)
    Ext.getCmp('listeEditionDossierGridPanel').getStore().loadData(listDossier); // Not ok
```

Other exemple with Ajax Proxy :

```
var fields = [
                {name: 'code', mapping : 'code'},
                {name: 'avis', mapping : 'demande.avis'},
                {name: 'commentaire', mapping : 'demande.commentaire'},
                {name: 'id', mapping: 'demande.id'}
            ];

store = new Ext.data.Store({
                    fields: fields,
                    autoLoad: true,
                    proxy: {
                        type: 'ajax',
                        extraParams: {jsonRequest:JSON.stringify(valeurs)},
                        url : 'chargerDossiersEligibles.do',
                        reader: {
                            type: 'json',
                            root: 'dossiersEligibles'
                        }
                    }
                });
```

In this case all is fine and the datas can map.

Cheers

Benoit